# Files pull from GitHub contain HEAD >>>>>>>>?

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

I update all my files on my server via GitHub. But yesterday I did a "git pull" but the files that were downloaded were corrupted so when I checked the website they were weird things appearing. It was written `HEAD >>>>>>>>>>` I don't remember the rest... And some weird token code

What could of caused this?

Is there a way for me to check after a pull if the files are corrupted or not?

I have iptables setup...

Using Linux Ubuntu 12.

Comment: Did you checkout the hash value, before/after uploading the files?

Comment: What do you mean that the files are "corrupted"? ***How*** are they corrupted? Do you have conflict markers in them that you never resolved? Or is something else wrong? Please clarify!

Comment: When I did another pull it was ok. It was written HEAD >>>>>>>>>> I don't remember the rest... And some weird token code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HEAD >>>>>>>>>>

looks like a merge marker.  Most likely, there was a merge conflict, and you committed the result without resolving the merge.

The easiest way to resolve merge conflicts is to use `git mergetool`.  See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging